# Pass command as a function parameter in Windows

Tags: batch-file

I should pass a command as a function parameter to another command.

```
dir.bat

@echo off
echo file1.txt
echo file2.txt
echo file3.txt
```

```
print.bat 

@echo off
echo %*
```

My question is this.

```
> dir.bat | print.bat -opt1

=== expected result ===

-opt1 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

and sometimes the result of dir.bat is bigger than 8K.
How can I pass the result of a command as a parameter?

Comment: You could write it as a temporary file and then pass the filename...

Comment: Please show me the code.

Comment: I tried to the way you commented. But when the file list is too long( > 8K ), it doesn't work. Because the max length of DOS command is 8K.

Comment: Simple, you can't use a paramter bigger than 8K. But a program that expects much data should provide an option to read the parameters from a file